# Shell script to copy list of files with spaces

Tags: bash, filenames

I am trying to create a small script that takes a filename, in which the absolute location of files are listed, and to copy it to some other location.

Content of the file `test.txt` for example:

```
/home/public/Music/Disk/GameOfThrones/Season1/01 Main Title.mp3
```

Script tried:

```
for file in `cat test.txt`; do cp "$file" temp ; done
```

However, this script thinks there are three files. Some more searching yield the following file:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for file in `cat test.txt`; do cp "$file" temp ; done
IFS="$OIFS"
```

which seems to replace each occurrance of the letter 'n' by a newline.

So how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `while` loop with `read`, not `for`:

```
while read -r file ; do
    cp "$file" temp
done < test.txt
```

Comment: See [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving `` `...` `` (or its newer form `$(...)`) unquoted is the split+glob operator.

The splitting part is done on the characters of `$IFS`, by default, SPC, TAB and newline. Here, you want to split on newline only, and don't want the glob part. So it's:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline only. IFS=$'\n' also works in some shells
set -o noglob # disable the glob part
cp -- $(cat test.txt) temp/
```

With `zsh` which has an explicit splitting operator, it can be simplified to:

```
cp -- ${(f)"$(cat test.txt)"} temp/
```

With GNU tools, you can also do:

```
xargs -d '\n' -ra test.txt cp -t temp
```

(which will also have the benefit to work around the limit on the size of the arguments in case there is a large number of files to copy).